# phone log for android and ios

Tags: android, ios

I am a java student, I am starting my internship next month
I have been given a project to research on, on an app that can download phone log(messages and phone calls) from an Android and IOS mobile

here's the little of what I've compiled
"the next generation of smartphone surveillance software. This mobile tracker application records the incoming and outgoing phone calls, sms and surroundings. It tracks gps locations, the browser activity and messages from applications like Whatsapp, Facebook, Viber, Skype and Line."

PLEASE HELP!!..any suggestions will be most appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you'll be able request permissions to access:

1. Call logs - incoming and outbound
2. Messages - complete access, including content
3. Data use - Data use over WiFi and mobile network since the device was last turned on (not historical). There's also a "fun" bug that this API doesn't work well if the device WiFi is turned on.
4. You won't be able to get access to other applications information without a rooted device. Whatsapp messages, for instance, will be stored in a database in Whatsapp's private memory area.

On iOS, you'll have a much harder time. Access to historical call logs and messages is out of the questions on any non-private APIs (so if you access any, you can't publish the application). The same will apply for information from any applications.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you can view the logs within Xcode while running the project.

But Apple does not allow an app to download iPhone Messages and call logs. This is private data so such apps have **strong chances of rejection by Apple review team**.

Comment: "But Apple does not allow an app to download iPhone Messages and call logs. This is private data so such apps have strong chances of rejection by Apple review team."-even if i still use Xcode?